# How to set organizer in google calendar event

Tags: php, icalendar

Here I am creating a google calendar event with benu library which I have download from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bennu/

```
include('../lib/bennu.inc.php');

echo '<pre>';
echo "\n";

$a = new iCalendar;
$ev = new iCalendar_event;
// Summary and description; also resources
$ev->add_property('summary', 'Blablabla');
$ev->add_property('description', 'These are: some "notes" for this event');
$ev->add_property('resources', array('one of this', 'one of that'));
$ev->add_property('organizer','sanjayrathod885@gmail.com');

// Start-end date
$ev->add_property('class', 'PRIVATE');
$ev->add_property('dtstart', '20160202', array('value' => 'DATE'));
$ev->add_property('dtend', '20160203', array('value' => 'DATE'));
$ev->add_property('dtstamp', '20160202T235601Z');

$ev->add_property('attendee', 'mailto:sanjay@logicexpress.in', array('cn' => 'John Papaioannou', 'delegated-from' => array('mailto:bla@some.net', 'mailto:bla@some.net')));

$a->add_component($ev);
$message2 = $a->serialize();
```

So I am setting the organizer like this

```
$ev->add_property('organizer','sanjayrathod885@gmail.com');
```

I am not getting the desired output.
So how can I set the organizer with this library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your organizer should be a mailto: uri, just like attendee